# Showing previous $_GET results

Tags: php, post, dropdown

I have a table controlled by a dropdown box. My dropdown for example has all animals, lion, crocodile, and wolf. When I press lion results show fine, I then click crocodile and again results are fine but when I click the browser back button I can no longer see the previous results. What I want is after I click crocodile to be able to click the browser button and it to show previous results from the lion I clicked here is my code so far: I have also tried storing as local storage to no avail. The session is collected and posted onto a separate page

```
<form id='id' method='get' name='myform'> 
    <!--<select name='fetching' class='filter' id='fetching' onchange = "getSelectValue()">  -->
    <select name='fetching' class='filter' id='fetching'> 
        <option selected='true' disabled='disabled'>Select option </option> 
        <option value='All'>All</option> 
        <optgroup label='rare'>
        <?php
        $s = "SELECT DISTINCT species,status from animal"; 
        $result = $con->query($s);
        if($result = mysqli_query($con, $s)){
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    if($row['status']=='rare'){
                        $output = "<option value='".$row['species']."'";    //keeps select option on dropdown the same upon page refresh
                        if($_GET['fetching'] == $row['species']){
                             $output .= " selected='selected'";
                        }
                        $output .= ">".$row['species']."</option>";
                        echo $output;
                        if($_GET['fetching']){
                            // $output .= " selected='selected'";
                            $_SESSION['animal'] = $_GET['fetching'];
                            header("Location: room.php?pn=1"); //added 12.04.22
                            exit;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: use the method GET not POST

Comment: and don't use sessions. select the chosen info from database

Comment: im using sessions to i can post the  the  results on another page though

Comment: DO NOT use sessions. select the chosen info from database

Comment: session is used to allow posting  of table results on another page. This in turn can be controlled by my dropdown filter

Comment: This is NOT how web applications work. You should use GET method, not session

Comment: I've made these changes and with the get i still run into the same issue of it not being able to show previous get results